Is AES A Bijective Function
I wanted to ask whether AES is a bijective function, if I'm only observing it in the context of encrypting a single block.
Suppose, I'm working with keys of size 256, and I've fixed a key $k_0\in\{0,1\}^{256}$.
I'm asking whether it is correct to state that $AES_{k_0}()$ is a bijective function from $\{0,1\}^{128}$ to $\{0,1\}^{128}$.
I know that two different plaintexts $m_1,m_2 \in \{0,1\}^{128}$ would surely result in
$AES_{k_0}(m_1)\not=AES_{k_0}(m_2)$ so the decryption under $k_0$ will be possible, which leads to the fact the that AES is a single-valued function in the mentioned context.
If I'm not mistaken, (If I'm only looking at one block of size 128) this makes a $AES$ a single-valued function between two sets of the same size, and thus a bijection.
Am I missing something?
Thanks


All AES variants have 128-bit blocks. AES-128,192,256 refer to the key length.

Thanks, I'll edit the question accordingly.

Relevant fact: any injective function from a finite set to itself is a bijection.

AES has a block size of 128 bits.  Do you mean Rijndael with a block size of 256?

You are not missing anything. The easiest way to show that AES is bijective is that it is made of permutations and substitutions and those permutations and substitutions are all bijective.
